# React Rails: Objects are not valid as a react child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using rails 5.1 with the react-rails gem.

My model has a "start_time" column that uses the "tod" (time of day gem), so it is serialized in my model like this:

```
serialize :start_time, Tod::TimeOfDay
```

I need to parse this time in my react view, but I don't understand how to render the resulting object.

```
console.log(@props.booking.start_time) #=> Object {hour: 10, minute: 15, second: 0, second_of_day: 36900}
```

When I try to render it in a view I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {hour, minute, second, second_of_day}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
```

Should I parse the attribute in the model before sending it to react, or there is a react way to parse (and format) the array?

EDIT: added the view code

```
@Booking = React.createClass
  render: ->
    React.DOM.tr null,
      React.DOM.td null, @props.booking.start_time
```

Comment: can post the code where you are rendering time in view? @TopperH

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy, yes, sure, just updated my question with the view code

Comment: Here `React.DOM.td null, @props.booking.start_time` you are passing a hash of values to DOM but you shouldn't. create a sentense that you want to display in `td` from `@props.booking.start_time` and pass that sentense there. it will work. like `React.DOM.td null, timeToDisplay`.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy should the parsing be done in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let time = @props.booking.start_time
let timeToDisplay = time["hour"] + ":" + time["minute"] + ":" + time["second"]
```

Do it like this and pass that value to `td`. i think it works.

```
React.DOM.td null, timeToDisplay
```

Comment: Great, thank you. How would you make it handle a nil "start_time" field?

Comment: @TopperH it's better to handle it in back end side rather than in views.